# Using Python to Automate "Generate Scripts" option in Management Studio to get the data from local SQL Server and save it in a .sql file

Tags: sql-server, scripting, ssms

I want to use Python to automate the "Generate Scripts" option in Management Studio so that I can get the data from tables which are stored on local SQL Server and save it into a `.sql` file.

I want to save it in an SQL file so that later another user can access and verify the data on SSMS, even if he does not have access to the local SQL Server.

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated as I have been trying this for sometime now.

I tried using dataframes to fetch the data from SQL Server and then writing it into a csv file. Then I am not able to store it in a `.sql` file from csv.

Comment: Automating SSMS is essentially a no-go. Using SMO (Server Management Objects) is a better idea, but it's a .NET technology and probably not that easy to use from Python (unless you involve IronPython, perhaps). If you need the database schema in addition to the data, consider [extracting a DACPAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sqlpackage) for easy deployment later. If you only need the data, the canonical tool for import and export is `bcp`. It will not produce a `.sql` file with commands, but that's a really slow and ideally avoided way to import data anyway.

Comment: Your goal does not make much sense. A script (.sql file) that contains hundreds (or more) insert statements will be of little use to anyone who does not have access to some sql server instance with the appropriate schema. Use Jeroen's suggestion or just create a full database backup.

Comment: Sorry. I meant the other user has access to his own local SQL server but not mine. Then he can run the script on his own instance.

Comment: You're still not thinking through all the issues that can arise. Your tables have primary and foreign keys defined. You will need a much more complicated script to handle primary and foreign key conflicts. I still say the backup is much safer. Give that person a backup and use it to create a second version of the database and let that person copy whichever rows are needed.

Comment: @SMor: backups have the distinct drawback that they cannot be restored on earlier versions of SQL Server than the one they were created with. If you're free to install whatever version you please as an Express or LocalDB instance that's not too bad, but otherwise it can be quite annoying.

Answer (score 4):

[`mssql-scripter`](https://pypi.org/project/mssql-scripter/) does exactly what you want. This is a free and MIT licensed command line tool by Microsoft to export data and/or schema of a database. It can generate backward compatible scripts to older versions of SQL Server.
The output script can be run in SSMS.

The following command line dumps the data from a database to `dump_file.sql` in a SQL Server 2008 compatible format.

```
python -m mssqlscripter -S <hostname> -d <databasename> -U <user> -P <password> -f .\dump_file.sql --data-only --target-server-version 2008
```

If you want to use the `mssqlscripter` from within a python script the following snippet does the same thing as the above command line.

```py
import mssqlscripter.main as scripter

scripter.main(['-S', 'hostname',
               '-d', 'databasename',
               '-U', 'user',
               '-P', 'password',
               '-f', r'.\dump_file.sql',
               '--data-only',
               '--target-server-version', '2008'])
```

Further useful options are available, see the builtin help with

```
python -m mssqlscripter -h
```